# Delete data in HDFS files and tune Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I have a script that **deletes rows** in txt files stored in the **HDFS**. Data is partitioned by day with less than `10MB` data per partition.

the code reads all the data into a dataframe (`DF1`), keeping track or the src data, so I can re-write the data at the end.
Then based on another single column dataframe (`DF2`), removes all rows that contain any string on the `DF2`.

The amount of data is not big, although the code takes too long to complete.

How should be Spark configured to run? More executors, cores, memory?
Or perhaps I could handle the *Dataframe* in a different way?

Comment: If the two dataframes have row IDs then do a broadcast join, filter and a drop for optimal performance

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast DF2 and run the same process. This should improve the performance.

For decreasing the runtime further, you can increase the number of executors (--num-executor). Since each partition is only around 10Mb, I'd suggest you to use minimal resource for each executor (--executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 1).

These are the few options which can be used right away to reduce the runtime. By analysing the data further and the serialisation used, you can try further optimising it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for data that size, is it possible to just not use Spark? Instead read in the raw resources and run them on a VM/Container?

We need to know more about the configuration you're using now to provide advice: How many cores are you currently using? Is it close to max utilization?

Also, code samples help a lot with diagnosing the problem.